# Error conectando a un servidor SQL mediante una conexión SQLOLEDB usando QtSQL / QSqlDatabase

Tags: python, sql, qt, pyside2

Estoy tratando de conectarme a un servidor SQL mediante QtSql.

El problema es que necesito una conexión tipo "SQLOLEDB", y lo más parecido que encuentro son "ODBC" los cuales usan Drivers, y yo tengo un Provider...

Por lo que ese formato (el que muestro a continuación) no vale.

```
connection_string = ("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=XXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXX;User Id=XXXX;Password=XXXX")
db = QSqlDatabase().addDatabase("???", connection_string)
db.open()
```

Cualquier ayuda seria muy agradecida! Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo he resuelto de la forma que explico en el [foro ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71478247/error-conecting-sqloledb-with-qtsql-qsqldatabase?noredirect=1#comment126339273_71478247).

Allí explico lo siguiente:
Finally I've managed to connect to the server using a DSN like this:

```
db32 = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QODBC")
        db32.setHostName("yourServerHost")
        db32.setDatabaseName("dsnnameinODBCWindowsManager")
        db32.setUserName("XXXX")
        db32.setPassword("XXXX")
        ok32 = db32.open()
```

Before you must configure a ODBC DSN in your PC using ODBC Windows Manager, and get it to connect to your database.
Comments:

1. Make sure the architecture of your DSN matches your Python (32 or 64 bit).
2. Repeat the User and Password info when creating the DSN in ODBC Windows Manager and when connecting when using QtSql as shown.

Hope it helps anyone!

Espero que a alguien le pueda servir de ayuda, muchas gracias igualmente!

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).